I want to plot the decision boundaries of an SVM model with more than 2 variables
I understand that that is impossible to visualize, so I went in and PCA-transformed the variables. The problem is that I still need more than 2 principal components to get "good" classification results. If I only plot the first 2 PCs I get a plot that doesn't correspond to the classification results. Can I show one plot with PC1 and PC2, and another with PC3 and PC4? Or is that useless? The reason I want a plot in the first place is because the person who wants the classification model insists on it.

How many PCs / variables do you want to work with & display?  Can you post a small example daataset for people to work with?
